# How to validate url in optional field

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to validate URL but in form optional field , i want if user have no website it allow to post data in database but if he/she enter wrong url give error.

```
if  (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)){ 
    $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Wrong Website";
}
```

Comment: `if(condtion){ do something } else{ well, you know }`

Comment: *"MY CODES:"* - I sense code droppings to follow in comments... Edit: I was right. Please don't do that. Edit your question and place it in your question and not in comments, thanks. and delete that from comments after.

Comment: `test_input()` oh, and there's more where that comes from, *am sure*.

Comment: *I'm blowing bubbles again.*

Comment: Please take a tour about SO: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and do something your self, if you then encounter problem, formulate your question and people can give better answers!

Comment: I try to add in my question but i get error question format, i read in knowledge base but nothing .

Comment: Paste your code in the edit method http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31035305/edit then highlight all the code and then use CTRL-K then save.

Comment: I 'm already put  codes in question..

Comment: where did you find this code, here? http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/285024-preg-match-can-someone-explain-this-to-me/ ?

Comment: Others "else if " above its okay, but this did good for wrong URL but i don't want to be mandatory .

Comment: i found here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
if($website != "" && !preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $website)){ 
    $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Wrong Website";
}
```